# What is this dialogue referring to in S01E12?

Tags: dialogue, frisky-dingo

In the S01E12 of *Frisky Dingo*, "Penultimate Fighting", one of the characters says:

> He's like a kid in a candy shop, and that candy is... success. And I'm that friendly man at this cash register with a handle bar mustache *chuckles*

another character responds:

> I think I'm missing the key reference.

I've got to admit that I'm also missing the key reference here. Does anyone know what this could be referring to?